# Is there a way to look for a role ping? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, roles, mention

Title says it all.
I tried looking for the id:

`if "845314564555931660" in message.content:`
I tried looking for the id in an integer:
`if 845314564555931660 in message.content:`
The integer recognizes it but gets an error because it's looking for an int in a str.
I tried converting the id into a ping:
`if <@845314564555931660> in message.content:`

I tried using the ping alone:

`if "@Sugarcane" in message.content:`

None can detect the message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`discord.Message.role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.role_mentions) or [`discord.Message.raw_role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.raw_role_mentions) attributes.

- `.role_mentions` returns a list of `discord.Role` objects that were mentioned in the message
- `.raw_role_mentions` returns a list of role IDs as integers.